# МОЖНО ЛИ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ РАЗНЫЕ ТИПЫ СКАЗУЕМЫХ в одном предложении

Tags: сказуемые

[Синтаксические ошибки | Культура письменной речи - gramma.ru](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=10.11) Нарушение в области однородных сказуемых: использование разных типов сказуемых в качестве однородных: "Море после шторма спокойное, ласковое и играет лучами солнца";

[Современный русский язык | Валгина Н.С. - hi-edu.ru](http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/index.html) Однородные члены могут иметь одинаковое морфологическое выражение, но могут быть морфологически разнородными, например: а) Воздух был редок, неподвижен, звучен (Л. Т.); б) Всегда он был бледен, худ, подвержен простуде, мало ел, дурно спал (Ч.).

В предложении о море разве не морфологически разнородные сказуемые?

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В литературе часто используются сказуемые разных типов в одном предложении при одном подлежащем. 
Поиск в Нацкорпусе по запросу "энергичен" :

> Вадим Кожевников. Щит и меч. Книга вторая (1968)
> Он был бодр, энергичен и свирепо командовал людьми.
> М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 2 (1960)
> ― Досмерти люблю, когда командир энергичен и быстро принимает правильное решение…
> В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. Ч. 1-4 (1913-1932)
> Он молод, сведущ, энергичен и желал бы попасть на новое крупное дело, а здесь, где все на колесах и все сто лет тому назад предрешено, ему не место...

Однородные сказуемые представлены в виде СИС, СГС, ПГС.

Answer (score 0):

> В предложении о море разве не морфологически разнородные сказуемые?

Они там не только морфологически, но и грамматически (синтаксически).